# How to handle push notifications for same user in more devices, more browsers

Tags: push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I have an hybrid website created with Ionic on Firebase, so I have even the PWA version, an android version and an iOS version, the user can be free or authenticated.

Now I am in a problem 'cause I dont have idea how to handle the push notifications when an user could access the first time my website, then he choses to receive notification and I store on my database his/her token to send push notifications, everything ok this user has 1 token.

Now this user become registered then when he access the website I dont know this is the same user as before then I receive a new request to store a new token.

At this time this same user has 2 token in my database.

Now if the user another day will visit my website with another browser, for example firefox and accept again the notification then he has now 3 tokens on my DB.

If the same user now even install the PWA version I will get another different token and my system will store even this, now this user has 4 tokens.

Keeping going further with this examples an user could collect 6 or more tokens stored on my database.

The problem is that if now I send a notification, this user will be overhelmed by my informations and is going to receive 6 or more notifications every time I send out 1.

Which is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: Details are great but still need to know what is the notfication library ur using.. is it onesignal or other notfication library?

Comment: ah yes your're right, I use Firebase and FCM

Comment: Did you get any results?